# Computer time and bios resets everytime I unplug from wall

Tags: motherboard, bios, power-supply, battery, desktop-computer

I am using an [Asus P5GC-MX motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5GCMX/) with a 700 watt power supply and I cannot figure out why this is happening.

First I tried a new good brand battery with no luck. Next I flashed my BIOS and updated it and still no luck.

I have checked the pins on the battery tray and cleaned them. Then I went and bought a brand new PSU and installed it again with another new battery just in case the first was drained and no luck.

The computer keeps track of time and BIOS when I power off, but when I physically unplug it is when it resets? Does anyone have any suggestions? The last thing I can think of is a new motherboard, but before it comes to that I hope someone can help.

Comment: Sounds like the battery "holder" on the mobo might have a bad solder, disconnecting it from the rest of the board... Which would mean you need to replace the mobo - or just not disconnect in from mains :)

Comment: A volt meter would tell you alot about what's going on.  With the batter installed measure from where the battery connects to the MB

Comment: @zagrimsan +1 but I wouldn't replace a mobo over this. I'd fix the solder joint (or possibly just bend the holder back into place if that was the issue)

Comment: @krowe I suspect that it might be hard or even impossible to fix, at least it'll require good skill with soldering to avoid breaking it more badly... but of course, it might not hurt much trying.

Comment: Not to be left out. the possiblity that the cmos jumper the Clearing jumper is set in the wrong position, which would usually cause more different problems.  When already messing with clearing, prior to having a battery problem, you have to check that too.

Comment: What BIOS settings if any have you changed from default and are trying to retain?

Comment: The clock is the only BIOS I changed

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't normally connect your machine to the Internet, I would just suggest relying on NTP (network time protocol). This can be configured under most operating systems. This will save you the headache of troubleshooting your hardware. But if you enjoy hardware troubleshooting, I would recommend that as well. The focus on NTP assumes the main issue is the clock and not any BIOS setting that deviates from default. No particular BIOS settings are mentioned. If BIOS settings are being changed and need to be retained, then yes a hardware fix would be needed to avoid having to reset them after power has been removed and restored.

Comment: Low quality answer.  OP is also losing the BIOS configuration; NTP cannot solve that.  You don't comprehend the scope of the problem.

Comment: You're correct, I overlooked/neglected the aspect of the BIOS configuration being lost. However, though the clock is mentioned, no (other) particular configuration of the BIOS is mentioned. So I assumed, and perhaps incorrectly, that the main issue was the clock. Point taken though. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanS - Update your answer then.  You could salvage it provided you put some work into it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for the support. I added the last sentence indicating my assumption. I also queried the OP (original poster) to see if there were BIOS setting if any that differed from default. Will add a little more. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct, the issue is the clock.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the clarification. Let us know if utilizing NTP works for you. If it does, you might accept the answer. It can be helpful to others with the same or a similar problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but am having difficulty understanding what to do with NTP. Is there a page where it simplifies what I have to do ? I don't mind learning but I don't understand it.

Comment: What OS are you running? On most if you go to the "system folder" or "system control folder" there should be a date and time configuration that you can open. Once opened, there should be an option for enabling the use of the network time protocol. You might also check the time zone setting to ensure it is correct, but it probably is. A web search for your OS and NTP might prove fruitful too if you haven't already tried that.

Comment: Oh, if you meant sync with internet time, then yes, I tried that as well as checked time zone

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_date_it_overview.mspx?mfr=true suggests that if synchronization isn't occurring then it may be a firewall issue. I'm guessing that is not your issue but it could be. I just started up my Windows 7 VM and it sync'ed soon after startup. I have sync with internet time server checked and set to time.windows.com

Comment: @Tom: I'm assuming you've made no further progress on this. Still not getting the time sync'ed.

Comment: I'm not sure how or why, but one day it decided to just start working. Its a total mystery to me.

Comment: @Tom: Great. Probably just a configuration and/or connection issue in combination with a reboot. Glad it is working now. You might accept the answer at this point if you feel it does a reasonable job at providing direction for a solution. This is useful to others that come along and examine the thread.